# Why is j_free function and free_ptr pointer needed in glibc?

Tags: libc

I am disassembling `libc-2.23.so`, there exists a thunk method called `j_free` which jumps at the location pointed to by `free_ptr` pointer in glibc. Why do those even exist while `free()` itself is exported?

### [image]

Comment: what exactly are you disassembling?

Comment: I am disassembling `libc-2.23.so`, seems that `j_free` is a thunk method

Answer (score 3):

In ELF, all symbols are global. it means that a symbol in another module (e.g. main executable) can override the glibc's `free`. that's why all calls to it go through a GOT pointer. On the first call, the dynamic linker will go through all symbols in all modules and pick up the first one offering `free`. If no other modules export it, the libc one will be used.

Comment: Does it make sense to have calls internal to `libc` to be routed through `plt` instead of a relative call?

Comment: yes, because it needs to be prepared for possibility that they're overridden by an external module.